# Javascript - getting the background color of the hovered element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently making a google chrome extension and am using this javascript to change dynamically the background color of the hovered element:

```
var bindEvent = function(elem ,evt,cb) {
    //see if the addEventListener function exists on the element
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener(evt,cb,false);
    //if addEventListener is not present, see if this is an IE browser
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        //prefix the event type with "on"
        elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, function(){
            /* use call to simulate addEventListener
             * This will make sure the callback gets the element for "this"
             * and will ensure the function's first argument is the event object
             */
             cb.call(event.srcElement,event);
        });
    }
};


bindEvent(document,'mouseover', function(event) 
{ var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    /* getting target.style.background and inversing it */
});

bindEvent(document,'mouseout', function(event) 
{ var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    /* getting target.style.background and inversing it */
});
```

and when used with static values, like `target.style.background = #FFFFFF;` when the cursor hover an element and `target.style.background = #00000;` when the cursor leave the element, it works perfectly. However, when I try to get the value of `target.style.background` or even `target.style.backgroundColor`, I always get `rgb(255,255,255)`, no matter what the background color of the element is.

I know how to convert rgb to hexa and how to inverse it, but if I can't get the initial value of the background, it's useless.

So, my question is: why do `var foo = target.style.backgroundColor;` always return `rgb(255, 255, 255)` and how do I get the correct value?

Additional notes: the extension will be ported to other browsers later, so a cross-browser solution would be nice if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, `target.style` is only populated with inline styling. To get style including css definitions just use the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) method. For example

```
//instead of this
target.style.backgroundColor

//try this
getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor
```

*Note that using the `getComputedStyle` method returns a `read-only` object, and `target.style` should still be used to set the background color.

Comment: Please note that getComputedStyle is not supported in at least IE6/7 and will throw an error, so you should use 'currentStyle' method instead. 
Also how does this help him get the hover colour?

Comment: I replaced `target.style.backgroundColor` with `getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor` when trying to get the color and I get a different result depending on the hovered background color now! Thank you.
@marksyzm : I will remember that and use it when doing the IE extension.

Comment: @marksyzm It is, however, supported in IE9+. I don't think many people develop for IE6 anymore, anyway. Also he wanted to get the color of the element on hover, not the hover color of the element.

Comment: Fair enough, BeardFist... oh I accidentally downvoted the comment by the way and couldn't 'undo' it which is a pain - sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.style` to get settings that haven't been defined using `.style` or `style=""`. Most browsers implement other ways for getting at current style calculations, these are a minefield of oddities however.

Internet explorer has `.currentStyle`, whereas the rest tend to implement `.getComputedStyle`. It would be a good idea to read up on these two subjects, to see their implementation — however, as I have said retrieving style settings is a much more complicated process than it first seems.

Even jQuery's `css` method only returns settings that have been specifically determined on that element i.e. no inheritance.

The following could be of use however:

http://upshots.org/javascript/jquery-get-currentstylecomputedstyle

Comment: I won't forget to replace `.getComputedStyle` with `.currentStyle` when doing the IE extension.

Comment: @CaramelTruffle Good good :) Just as a warning, it's not a straight replace, as you can most probably tell from BeardFirst's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I know of is to associate a CSS class or ID with a colour, then extract that from an anchor in a hidden element, or simply from empty anchor tag with the class applied. Otherwise it really is about knowing what that colour is and having it already stored as a value somewhere. My HTML would be the following for this solution:

```
<style>
a:hover,
a#yourChosenIdName {
background-color:#00FF00;
}
</style>

<a href="#" id="yourChosenIdName"><!-- --></a>

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('yourChosenIdName'),
    getStyle = el.currentStyle ? el.currentStyle : getComputedStyle(el),
    hoverBackgroundColor = getStyle.backgroundColor;
//do something with background-color
</script>
```

Comment: You've got a slight logic error in your code. `getComputedStyle` is not interchangable with `currentStyle`, the former is a method, the latter an object.