# Webpage color retrive work fine with jQuery but not with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, element

I create a jQuery function that retrieves colors used into a webpage :

```
$('*').each(function(i, el){    

var $element = $(el),
color = $element.css('background-color');

if(!~$.inArray(color, colors))
    colors.push(color);

});
```

and it work fine for me.
Now I need to convert this code into pure javascript and I wrote this:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')),
len = elements.length,
i, node, color;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
 node = elements[i];
 color = node.style.backgroundColor;

 if (color && !~colors.indexOf(color)) {
  colors.push(color);
 }
}
```

but element node.style.backgroundColor is ever empty, for every element, like in this screenshot

[image]

why in jquery all is done and with javascript conversion script dosen't work fine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892725/javascript-getting-the-background-color-of-the-hovered-element

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getComputedStyle` method for css styles as `node.style.backgroundColor` applies only for inline styles (as suggested in this question [Javascript - getting the background color of the hovered element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892725/javascript-getting-the-background-color-of-the-hovered-element) )

```
//try this
getComputedStyle(target).backgroundColor
```